# ASP.NET MVC: Set parent foreign key while creating a child entity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have:

"Task" Entity that holds a foreignkey to a "Project" Entity.
In the MVC model I have a ProjectDetails view where i have a ActionLink for creating a new Task

I need to set the ProjectReference for the new Task object.
The projectReference is passed by a url parameter (`CreateTask?projectId=4`)

In the projectDetails view I have:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Create New Task", "CreateTask", new {???Set the ProjectID???  })%>
```

1) How to set the ProjectReference "ProjectID"?

2) Is using `ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider["id"].RawValue` for getting the urlparameter good?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just set the projectId in the model you're passing to the view? Something like:

```
public ActionResult ProjectDetails()
{
    ViewData["projectId"] = GetProjectId();

    return View();
}
```

Then in the view:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Create New Task", "CreateTask", ViewData["projectId"]) %>
```

Also, it's not a good practice to use Request.Params like that. Instead make an action with a "projectId" parameter like:

```
public ActionResult CreateTask(int projectId)
```

For more details see [Passing Data in an ASP.NET MVC Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394711.aspx)

Another thing is that one of the ideas of using ASP.NET MVC is to keep your urls readable. Try to use an url like `/projects/5/createtask/` instead of `/createtask.aspx?projectid=5`. For more details on this, look at [URL Routing with ASP.NET MVC](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/13/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx) by Scott Guthrie

Answer (score 0):

OK i found a solution but it's not that beautiful:

in projectdetails.aspx:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Create New Task", "CreateTask", new { projectId = ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider["id"].RawValue })%>
```

in taskcreateMethod:

```
int projectId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Params["projectId"]);
taskToCreate.Project= (from p in _db.Project where p.Id ==projectId select p).First();
_db.AddToTask(taskToCreate);
_db.SaveChanges();

return RedirectToAction("Details", "Home", new { id = projectId });
```